# password_verify function not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo, php-password-hash

Hey all i'm having issues with the password_verify function.
Register is working but for some odd reason it just says incorrect when i'm trying to use it for login.

Here's my code(don't judge please, i'm still fairly new to everything.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$SQLSelect = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
$SQLSelect -> execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
while ($show = $SQLSelect -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$passwordHash = $show['password'];
}
$date = strtotime('-1 hour', time());
$attempts=$odb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `loginlogs` WHERE `ip` = '$ip' AND `username` LIKE '%failed' AND `date` BETWEEN '$date' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()")->fetchColumn(0);

//Check fields
if (empty($username) || empty($password) || !ctype_alnum($username) || strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 15)
{
die(error('Please fill in all fields.'));
}

//Check login details
echo $passwordHash;
$SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
$SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => password_verify($password, $passwordHash)));
$countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
if (!($countLogin == 1))
{
$SQL = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `loginlogs` VALUES(:username, :ip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'XX')");
$SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username." - failed",':ip' => $ip));
die(error('Username or password are invalid.'));
```

Does anyone have a clue why this isn't working? i double checked everything and it should be fine, also the echo $passwordHash was just me checking if i was able to get the password which worked fine.
:/

Comment: I modified the code a little bit to see if this would work and it didn't change anything,
`$passwordVerified = password_verify($password, $passwordHash);
 $SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $passwordVerified));`

Comment: May be size of your column is too small and password hash is being truncated before saving to database .If it's size is less than varchar(255) then make it to varchar(255).

Comment: @RahulJha mine was at 40 after changing to 255 the hash was bigger but its still not working, maybe with my register?

$insertUser = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(NULL, :username, :password)");
$insertUser -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)));

Comment: $passwordVerified= password_verify($password, $passwordHash);
echo $passwordVerified;
What is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password_verify($password, $passwordHash)` this returns a boolean value. What you should do is to use it to verifies that a password matches a hash. Remove all this:

```
$SQLCheckLogin = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password");
$SQLCheckLogin -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => password_verify($password, $passwordHash)));
$countLogin = $SQLCheckLogin -> fetchColumn(0);
if (!($countLogin == 1))
```

And simply do this:

```
if (!password_verify($password, $passwordHash)) {
    // ...
    die(error('Username or password are invalid.'));
}
```

Comment: How do i verify the username if i go by this way?

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, just accepted it, thanks. How do i close this?